# Filling blank indices of multi-dimensional list then checking if full

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have one existing multi-dimensional list with predetermined (final) values `self.origBoard` and another multi-dimensional list of the same size, `self.board` that allows the user to fill in values. `self.origBoard` starts with a few blanks (whitespace) and other integer values, while `self.board` starts completely blank (empty).

The user is shown the combination of `self.origBoard` and `self.board` with the goal to have the user provide an integer value for all the indices from `self.origBoard` that started blank. I have some separate code to run upon the user filling in all the blanks, but I am having trouble determining in the code when this full-event occurs.

As an example, `self.origBoard` is is defined by:

```
self.origBoard[0]=' 19374652'
self.origBoard[1]='576182943'
self.origBoard[2]='342596718'
self.origBoard[3]='921753864'
self.origBoard[4]='638419527'
self.origBoard[5]='457628139'
self.origBoard[6]='185237496'
self.origBoard[7]='763941285'
self.origBoard[8]='29486537 '
```

This `self.origBoard` generates as expected, but I am having trouble dealing with the generation and full-checking of `self.board`. Here is my code for initializing `self.board`

```
self.board = [None] * 9      # Used to mark user-entered numbers
        for i in range(9):
            self.board[i] = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
```

I currently check whether it is full using this internal method:

```
def fullBoard(self):
        for i in range(0,9):
            for k in range(0,9):
                if self.board[i][k] == ' ':

                    return False
        return True
```

I fill in these blanks (' ') using this method which asks for user input.

```
def nextMove(self):
        row = int(input('Enter Row:'))
        col = int(input("Enter Column:"))
        num = input("Enter Number:")
        self.board[row][col] = num
```

Since the user will only be prompted to fill in the blanks from `self.origBoard`, (i.e. two indices in this example), I'm not sure how to check if the whole combined board is full.

Now I know why `fullBoard()` won't ever return true and that is because the remaining indices in `self.board` will remain `' '`. How can I check whether the combined values of `self.board` and `self.origBoard` represent a full board?

Minimal working code example below:

```
class Sudoku():

    def __init__(self):

        self.board = [None] * 9      # Used to mark user-entered numbers
            for i in range(9):
                self.board[i] = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]

        self.origBoard[0]=' 19374652'
        self.origBoard[1]='576182943'
        self.origBoard[2]='342596718'
        self.origBoard[3]='921753864'
        self.origBoard[4]='638419527'
        self.origBoard[5]='457628139'
        self.origBoard[6]='185237496'
        self.origBoard[7]='763941285'
        self.origBoard[8]='29486537 '

        self.board = self.origBoard

    def display(self):
        # display stuff
        pass

    def nextMove(self):
        row = int(input('Enter Row:'))
        col = int(input("Enter Column:"))
        num = input("Enter Number:")
        self.board[row][col] = num

    def fullBoard(self):
        for i in range(0,9):
            for k in range(0,9):
                if self.board[i][k] == ' ':

                    return False
        return True

    def winCheck(self):
        # Do some checks
        print("Testing ftw!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Sudoku()
    game.display()
    while(True):
        game.nextMove()
        if game.fullBoard() == True:
            break
            if game.winCheck() == True:
                game.display()
                print("You win!")
                break
            elif game.winCheck() == False:
                game.display()
                print("One or more of your numbers are overlapping!")
                continue
        else:
            game.display()
```

Comment: How do you define "full"? 9 integer values per row? What about spaces like your first and last lines?

`self.origBoard[0]=' 19374652'`

Would you want this origBoard to be seen as full or not?

Comment: That's a test board when I check the board it's after each turn (I fill in the spaces myself). As for a full board, every single index should have a number (string) inside of it and no blanks should be present.

Comment: So for the test board your current evaluation of fullBoard() returns True or False?

Comment: it should return True if the board is full, and false if it's not. It's constantly false because I can't figure out how to incorporate the "origBoard' into it.

Comment: Are `self.board` and `self.origBoard` supposed to be different? i.e. why are you not just storing these test values in `self.board`? You need to maintain the original values for some reason? I ask since in `fullBoard()` you are checking against `self.board` whereas you are storing the values in `self.origBoard`. In other words, `fullBoard()` should return True if you initialize your board with lines like `self.board[0]='019374652'` instead of `self.origBoard[0]='019374652'`

Comment: Of course, I didn't give you that code, I'm using origBoard because that value is not allowed to be changed, in sudoku you have numbers provided which aren't changeable, so there is a second board just for those values which can't be changed.

Comment: Ok, so I can't see any code that would populate the `self.board` list, thus if it never changes from the list of the initial ' ' values, `fullBoard()` should always return False. So where are you populating the `self.board` and are you sure it is actually getting filled?

Comment: For your test board, do you want `self.board` to eventually be identical to `self.origBoard` but with the space at the front and end being filled in?

Comment: Essentially yes, I want the boards to be exact copies of each other except when origBoard[0] = '019374652' it would be board[0][1] = 0 board[0][2] = 1 etc. That way it can track how many blanks are left. Also, I attatched the code above for my filling in and calling the functions.

Comment: Making a copy is of self.origBoard is as simple as `self.board = self.origBoard`. You can do that once, at the beginning of the game, then update the blanks with your nextMove() method. You need to know how many blanks are left or just if it is full or not? (These are two different issues).

Comment: I tried using your solution earlier in the day, but the problem is that origBoard is created by checking single characters in the string, for ex) self.origBoard[0]=' 19374652'. If I do self.board = self.origBoard, the self.board comes out as a 9 index'd list that cannot be checked by using board[i][k] (i,k sample variables).

Comment: Both self.origBoard and self.board should be 9x9 lists. The way you initialize self.origBoard would result in a 9x9 list (after the line:) `self.origBoard[8]='29486537 '`. So your copy would have to take place after this final row is created.  Also, to remove confusion, `self.origBoard[0]=' 19374652'` is not "checking" anything, it is assigning the string ' 019374652' to the 0th index of the list self.origBoard.

Comment: Yeah I get that, perhaps I'm a bit confused as to what I'm really trying to get here, I'm just trying to be able to check if my board is completely full and if it is then it'll run the winCheck function. Players will input their row and col number and the board will then be filled with the number they have so if they enter 4(row) 5(col) then index 4:5 should be whatever number they fill.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand your problem, and I am writing up an answer now, as it requires a bit of code to explain, which I cannot do here in the comments. I'll post in just a moment. Please comment on the answer if there something that shows I have misunderstood.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help, I'll look at it in the morning as I have to head off to bed. Once again, thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it seems the problem lies within the generation and assignment of values to `self.board` and the way the lists were setup (using strings as rows rather than another list). I'm guessing the user was confused by the fact that they could iterate through a string similar to how you can iterate through an array or list, but could not assign a value to a particular character, i.e. their previous `self.board[row][col] = num` was throwing an error of:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Even though `self.board[row][col]` will happily return a single character from the string.

From the code given, it seems the user needed to make a copy of `self.origBoard` prior to assigning new values to `self.board`. Without such a step, the `self.board` was never being populated with values other than the initial values of ' ', and those values assigned using the `nextMove()` method. Thus it makes sense that `fullBoard()` always returns False since the ' ' values would always remain in `self.board`. Example working code as follows:

```
class Sudoku():

    def __init__(self):
        # Note the one liner to replace your initializer for this
        self.origBoard = [[' '] * 9] * 9

        # Note the change from single strings to a list of integers
        self.origBoard[0]=[' ',1,9,3,7,4,6,5,2]
        self.origBoard[1]=[5,7,6,1,8,2,9,4,3]
        self.origBoard[2]=[3,4,2,5,9,6,7,1,8]
        self.origBoard[3]=[9,2,1,7,5,3,8,6,4]
        self.origBoard[4]=[6,3,8,4,1,9,5,2,7]
        self.origBoard[5]=[4,5,7,6,2,8,1,3,9]
        self.origBoard[6]=[1,8,5,2,3,7,4,9,6]
        self.origBoard[7]=[7,6,3,9,4,1,2,8,5]
        self.origBoard[8]=[2,9,4,8,6,5,3,7,' ']

        self.board = self.origBoard

    def display(self):
        # display stuff
        pass

    def nextMove(self):
        row = int(input('Enter Row:'))
        col = int(input("Enter Column:"))
        num = input("Enter Number:")
        self.board[row][col] = num

    def fullBoard(self):
        for i in range(0,9):
            for k in range(0,9):
                if self.board[i][k] == ' ':

                    return False
        return True

    def winCheck(self):
        # Do some checks
        print("testing ftw!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Sudoku()
    game.display()
    while(True):
        game.nextMove()
        if game.fullBoard() == True:
            # a break statement here would mean the following if statements are never reached
            if game.winCheck() == True:
                game.display()
                print("You win!")
                break
            elif game.winCheck() == False:
                game.display()
                print("One or more of your numbers are overlapping!")
                continue
        else:
            game.display()
```

Here I define "working" as I enter num values for index 0,0 and 8,8 which results in the call of `game.winCheck()`.

As a side note, I tried to use as much of the existing code as possible as this seems like some assignment to learn how lists and python work in general rather than something that needs to be optimized, but I've chosen to initialize each board a lot easier and avoid the unnecessary loop with:

```
self.board = [[' '] * 9] * 9
```

Or even better, you could use a Numpy array, and use the [all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) method to check if full rather than writing your own method to do so. i.e.

```
import numpy as np

self.board = np.zeros([9,9])

def fullBoard(self):
    np.all(self.board)
```